# Update a file inside existing MSI

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, cab

I am following these steps to extract a file from MSI and edit it and keeping it back. But when I install the new MSI, its not able to find the files inside the cabinet (.cab).

1. Extract the cab file from MSI

   `msidb -d "Setup.msi" -x Client.cab`
2. Extract the file from cab file.

   `cabarc X Client.cab *.* C:\ClientExtract\`
3. Edit the extracted file inside folder C:\ClientExtract
4. Create a new cab file from modified files

   `cabarc N Client.cab C:\ClientExtract\*.*`
5. Remove the existing cab from Setup.msi

   `msidb -d "Setup.msi" -k Client.cab`
6. Add the newly created cab file to msi

   `msidb -d "Setup.msi" -a Client.cab`

Now, this MSI file is not getting installed and its saying some file is not found.
When I am running steps1, 5 and 6 only, the MSI works smoothly. I believe the issue will be with cabarc.exe which is not able to maintain the folder structure.

Any help or alternative solution will be appreciated. msi2xml and xml2msi works but I cant use that.

Comment: I tried with that also but it does not helping

Comment: Yes, I am able to delete the cab file. I mean I deleted and then I created new cabinet file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question C#, I suggest writing a class library using the DTF interop libraries as helpers.  It's a robust programming platform compared to batch files.  You'll use the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller and Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab assemblies.

The way I prefer to do it is to leave the existing cab alone.  I create a new cab and stream it in.  I then update the File and Media table to register the cab and supersede the original file.

I have starter code I could share if you want to shoot me an email.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, and I too started coding in C#. My first approach was using WinSDk tools else C#. Please share your code, it may help in my code too.

Comment: It's an entire solution of projects.  Not something I can just paste into an answer.  Shoot me an email (I'm easy to find) and download the needed SDK from wix.codeplex.com.